# static files in pybb

Tags: django

I have some problems with static file, when i use them in `pybb`. I work on `django 1.3` and `python 2.6.5`.
My settings file is [here](http://pastebin.fobyfus.com/code/3/)

I put my css and images in /static/pybb/css and /static/pybb/images

when i put tag like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}pybb/my.css">
```

in my templates, it doesn't work. This is the same with image

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}pybb/images/myimage.jpg">
```

To sum it up, my own static files don't appear in my project templates.

any idea? perhaps i forgot something

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting css in package static files directory?
Also directories in STATICFILES_DIRS should not overlaps. Look at [example provided with pybbm](https://bitbucket.org/zeus/pybb/src/1befcb05b9e0/test/testapp) or even start project from this example.